# fetch array values and store it based on its own column but value is stored in different column

Tags: php

The html checkbox before query, I chose option 1 and option 4

[image: The checkbox value]

the data where the values should be stored, but it stores into option 1 and option 2 columns instead while it should store it inside both 'opt1' and 'opt4'

[image: Result inside the table]

PHP

```
if( isset( $_POST['picked'] ) )
        {
            $keepdata = array();

            $keepdata = $_POST['pick'];

            $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO traincheckbox VALUES ( null, '$keepdata[0]', '$keepdata[1]', '$keepdata[2]', '$keepdata[3]', '$keepdata[4]' )";

            mysqli_query( $sqlnrg, $sqlinsert );

            header( "Location: pick.php" );
        }
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pick[]" value="PAID"><label>Activity 1</label></input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pick[]" value="PAID"><label>Activity 2</label></input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pick[]" value="PAID"><label>Activity 3</label></input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pick[]" value="PAID"><label>Activity 4</label></input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pick[]" value="PAID"><label>Activity 5</label></input>
        <button type="submit" name="picked">Pick activities</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using name="pick[]" causes only to index checked checkboxes from 0 to n.

If you need explicit indexes, then you should force them:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pick[0]" value="PAID"><label>Activity 1</label></input>
```

and so on...

You should remove `$keepdata = array();` line from your code. It does nothing, because then it is initialized by `$_POST['pick']`.
Also have on mind, that values not marked as checked will not be sent in any form. There will be errors because of non-existent keys in array (if you check 1 and 4, then 2 and 3 will not be set). You need to handle this situation.

Comment: Wow, that was a lot of things I do not know what is going on within the array itself.
This answer clarify not just my problem but also my understanding on arrays. Thank you sir.
How about the 'foreach' loop thingy? How it will tolerate with the set that is not unset (such as radio button, it will only pass a single value). For example, three (3) radio buttons, I picked one (1) and foreach loop operates after I chose the value. What happens to the other null arrays?

Comment: Radio buttons are grouped by it's name. Web Browser should ensure that only one of radio buttons by unique name is selected and you will get only value for this very selected radio.